# IDEA I-Образный курсор

Tags: intellij-idea

В IDEA курсор стал I-образным, когда навожу на окно основного кода. Раньше был обычным курсором. Как вернуть обратно к стандартному виду?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

аааа. Извиняюсь. Открыл другую инстаняцию, так такой же курсор но только он белый и поэтому заметен, а вэтой инталяции он стал черным и ег вообще не видно. Как поменять его на белый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы не меняли ничего в настройках, нажмите `insert` на клавиатуре и все вернется к стандартному виду.

Если не помогает:

1. Идем в File -> Settigs ->  Editor -> General -> Appearance
2. Снимаем галочку с Use block caret

Поменять тему можно в
File -> Settigs ->  Editor -> Color Scheme -> выбираем Default

Comment: Пробовал. не помогает.

Comment: @Dmitrii Дополнил ответ

Comment: Увы. Не было галочки.

Comment: @Dmitrii а скрин, что происходит в окне с кодом, можете добавить?

Comment: На скрине курсора не видно. НАрисовал курсор (только курсор там черного цвета, белым для нагялдности нарисовал)

Comment: Так это и есть стандартное поведение... Как в обычных текстовых редакторах. Что Вас не устраивает?

Comment: Раньше там был курсор. т.е. белая стрелочка. Такая была изначально, после установки. А на курсор пободного вида переключалась в случае нажания на лкм. Хотя точно не помню. Возможно и не переклчалась на такой курсор, а была всегда стрелочкой

Comment: @Dmitrii Раньше, это когда не было текста? Наведите курсор на самое начало строки и будет вам стрелочка.

Comment: неа. в любое место окна с текстом ставлю, такой курсор. Есть там тест / нет, не важно

Comment: аааа. Извиняюсь. Открыл другую инстаняцию, так такой же курсор но только он белый и поэтому заметен, а вэтой инталяции он стал черным и ег вообще не видно. Как поменять его на белый?

Comment: @Dmitrii Бывает... Поменять можно, установив белую тему (Settings) -> Editor -> Color Scheme

Comment: @Dmitrii дополнил ответ. Закройте вопрос, поставив галочку, если он решил Вашу проблему.